# Why does this keep overwriting?

Tags: java

For some reason my program is overwriting the file and not adding to it.

This is the method that I am using to create the file and name it:

```
public void filenameMethod() throws IOException{

    System.out.println("Input the name of the file");

    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    filename = br.readLine();

    raf = new RandomAccessFile(filename, "rw");

}
```

I'm using this method to take in the input from the user, it sets the value to a variable that are then written to a file:

```
public void inputMethod() throws IOException{

    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

    System.out.println("Input Carname, ID, Existing Mileage, Gas Cost, Number of Days, Rate, Total Charge, Discount, Tax, Net Charge and Return Milage");

    String tokenString;
    tokenString = br.readLine();

    StringTokenizer st;
    st = new StringTokenizer(tokenString);

    carName = st.nextToken();
    id = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
    existingMileage = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
    gasCost = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
    ndays = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
    rate = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
    totalCharge = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
    discount = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
    tax = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
    netCharge = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
    returnMileage = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
}
```

I am then using this method to write them to a file:

```
public void fileWriterMethod() throws IOException{

    raf.writeInt(id);
    raf.writeInt(existingMileage);
    raf.writeInt(gasCost);
    raf.writeInt(ndays);
    raf.writeInt(rate);
    raf.writeInt(totalCharge);
    raf.writeInt(discount);
    raf.writeInt(tax);
    raf.writeInt(netCharge);
    raf.writeInt(returnMileage);
    raf.writeBytes(carName + "\r\n");

    //Closing the stream

    raf.close();

}
```

I don't understand why this is happening, can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you really attached to the usage of a `RnadomAccessFile`?

Comment: You might also want to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java

Answer (score 4):

`seek` to the end of your file before you start writing, for example:

```
File f = new File(filename);
long fileLength = f.length();
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(filename, "rw");
raf.seek(fileLength);
raf.writeInt(id);
...
```

Relevant [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#seek(long)).

Answer (score 3):

By default `RandomAccessFile` starts writing at start of file and will overwrite existing data. To write to end of file, you need to use skip to the end as follows:

```
raf.skipBytes( (int)raf.length() );
```

Answer (score 3):

When you open `RandomAccessFile` its pointer points to the beginning of the file. If you want to move to specific position you have to use method `seek()`. In your case you have to move to the end of file, i.e. `seek(fileLength)`:

```
File f = new File(filename);
long fileLength = f.length();
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(f, "rw");
raf.seek(fileLength);
// now write your bytes
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to append to the file, you need to [`seek(long)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#seek%28long%29) to the end. Something like,

```
raf.seek(raf.length());
```

From the linked Javadoc,

> Sets the file-pointer offset, measured from the beginning of this file, at which the next read or write occurs. The offset may be set beyond the end of the file. Setting the offset beyond the end of the file does not change the file length. The file length will change only by writing after the offset has been set beyond the end of the file.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to set the file pointer to the end of the file before you start writing, it defaults to the beginning.

```
raf.seek(raf.length());
```

placed before any of the write operations should do the trick.